# std::unique_ptr instantiate error trying to place inside std::map?

Tags: c++, boost, sfml

So I'm using SFML and Boost libraries trying to write a ResourceManager class. I'm using a std::map to contain the resources. I recently have heard that std::unique_ptr is really good because it of memory cleanup (or something along those lines).

This is what my ResourceManager class looks like:

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/Any.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include "Resource.h"


class ResourceManager
{
    public:
        ResourceManager();
        void clear();
        void dump();
        boost::any getResource(std::string s);
        sf::Texture loadTexture(std::string s, sf::IntRect d);
        void unloadTexture(std::string s);

    private:
        std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<boost::any>> resource;
};
```

Here is the method I'm trying to use to load objects into my map

```
sf::Texture ResourceManager::loadTexture(std::string s, sf::IntRect d)
{
    std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture> t;

    if (!t->loadFromFile(s, d))
        std::cout << "Error loading resource: " << s << std::endl;

    resource[s] = t;
}
```

However I get this error here at this line: [image: http://i.imgur.com/0uDZvvw.png]

Comment: sigh, I thought I was just being retarded with how I was using the unique_ptr. There's no exact guide I am follow, but I'll update my post better update describe my issue. give me a few mins <3

Comment: No. That's not how you do it. If there is no dynamic memory allocation, then `unique_ptr` doesn't make sense. Also, look into `std::make_unique` for when you *do* find a real use case. Maybe you should describe *what* you want to do, rather than *what* you are currently doing.

Comment: Well, programming by guessing does not work. And let's not use disgusting, disgraceful terms like "retarded", eh?

Comment: Also, you cannot copy a `unique_ptr` (because then it wouldn't be unique anymore). You can move it into a new location though, `something = std::move(r)`.

Comment: I better described my issue in my lead post, sorry for for unclear/indecisive. I was just trying to simplify my problem down to the core and try to figure the issue out.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: sorry, wasn't aware retarded was disgusting/disgraceful? but won't happen again!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retard_(pejorative)#Modern_use

Comment: okay im sorry @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Answer (score 1):

`std::unique_ptr` is a move-only time, meaning that you cannot copy it.

To fix it, use `std::move`:

```
resource[s] = std::move (t);
```

If it could be copied like you did, then you would have two `unique_ptr`'s pointing to the same object (which is non-sense since they are *unique*), so you must *move* it, calling the move-assignment-operator.

Comment: Aha!! That was it, thanks so much! I would upvote but no longer have above 15 rep ;-;

Comment: @Honor if answer answers your question, you should mark it as that.